# Creating a URL component for CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, components, cakephp-2.0

As an exercise i want to create a component for CakePHP framework.
I have been thinking about creating a URL component to deal with all the URLs stuff.

I was thinking about this methods:

- `getRealURL($shortedURL)`
- `getDomain($url)`
- `isSecure($url)`
- `getProtocol($url)`
- `getPort($url)`
- `getExtension($url)`
- `getShortURL($url)`
- `isYoutubeVideo($url)`
- `getParam($url, $var)`
- `getNumberOfParams($url)`
- `getParams($url, $vars)`
- `isImage($url)`
- `getURLFromText($text)`
- `eraseURlsFromText($text)`
- `shortURLsFromText($text)`

What do you think about it?
Any other ideas for the component?
Do you think the last 3 ones should not be in this component?

Any other suggestions will be welcome :)

Thanks.

Comment: not so sure this is a very helpful question - neither for you nor for anyone else for that matter..

Comment: Well. Is it so weird to ask for suggestions?

Comment: @Steve: Normally it's a great thing, but on a Q&A site, not so much. My only advice would be: *don't forget to write unit tests*. I'm afraid you're on your own regarding everything you've asked. Not trying to discourage you, please _do_ write the component, and please _do_ publish it (github or otherwise), but this is not the place to seek inspiration. In any case, good luck!

Comment: Thanks dr Hannibal Lecter for the clarification ;) I get it now :) Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a wild mix of things that are already available (port, url, ssl, params, protocol,... see response/request objects) and some really non-common things that should not go into the core of the framework.

Also this should not be a component, actually none of it, but in fact behaviors and helpers.

So if you want to do it create a plugin on github and publish it there.

Comment: Are they all available at CakePHP? Where? 
So, you would recommend me to create a helper instead of a component?